# Combining jQuery and normal JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically what I want to do is load some text from a .txt and stuff it inside a paragraph. I'm still in a phase of experimentation so what's happening is I have 2 buttons that load text into a paragraph. Both work from within the same javascript with a switch case.

```
case '6':
    vidljivo.innerHTML = slova.innerHTML;
    break;

case '7':
    $("#paragra").load( "1.txt" ); 
    break;
```

The first one (case 6) loads text from a hidden div on the page, but since that's clunky I want to put the data on an external document. That's what the other button should do (case 7) but when I click on it I get an error saying $ is not defined. Not sure what I'm doing wrong so any idea is appreciated.

You can see both the script and the page and all at https://student.fsb.hr/~pi201247/diy

Comment: jQuery **is** normal JS. It is just normal JS that someone has already written.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use functions provided by the jQuery library without using a `<script>` element to load the jQuery library (available from http://jquery.com )

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally forgot about putting that in... I was fiddling with js for 3 hours trying to get it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include JQuery in a script tag in your document.